# react navigation createMaterialTopTabNavigator transparent

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I'm trying to make the top tab buttons transparent, so the background behind them would be the background of their content screen. Is this behaviour possible to achieve with createMaterialTopTabNavigator?
I can't seem to find a way to make the tab buttons stick on top of the content. Can only make them appear above the screen content so there's only one fixed color for the tab buttons.
To make it clearer, let's say I have 3 screens, with red, green and blue backgrounds, I want the tab buttons to appear red green or blue, according to the focused screen

Answer (score 2):

Ok, so in case anyone else is looking for the same functionality, just set tabBarOptions style position: 'absolute'